# Should V.S May in subjunctive mood

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I was doing a grammar exercise the other day and was confused by the key to this question.

He’s working hard for fear that he _____.

1. should fall behind
2. fell behind
3. may fall behind
4. would fallen behind

The answer given is that A is correct. But I think C is much better.

What *is/are* the correct answers here?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112150/discussion-on-question-by-jianbin-yin-should-v-s-may-in-subjunctive-mood).

Answer (score 1):

In response to a similar question on [WordReference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/for-fear-that-he-should-would-fall-behind-others.3119500/):

> He is working hard for fear that he ____ fall behind others.
>
> **A** *should* **B** *would*?

Thomas Tompion responds

> The *should*/*shall* in the first person convention is appropriate for
> the ordinary future and conditional. Here we have a subjunctive
> created by a modal auxiliary and this would naturally be *should* rather
> than *would* where we wanted to give a more formal feel to the
> expression. One could also use *might*.
>
> I agree with [the previous contributor] that one could use either
> *should* or *would* here, or one might elide the auxiliary altogether – which would give an even greater feel of formality.
>
> Here are instances in the GB and US corpuses [[via Google
> ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+fear+that+he+would%3A+eng_us_2012%2Cfor+fear+that+he+should%3A+eng_us_2012%2Cfor+fear+that+he+would%3A+eng_gb_2012%2Cfor+fear+that+he+should%3A+eng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor)]
> of the different forms.
>
> - *For fear that he should fall behind* .... 0 (GB) - 0 (US)
> - *For fear that he would fall behind* ..... 1 (GB) - 14 (US)
> - *For fear that he might fall behind* ..... 2 (GB) - 7 (US)
> - *For fear that he fall behind* ................ 1 (GB) - 0 (US)
>
> Lest anyone think that means that the form with *should* isn't to be
> found, here are two examples from literature, one American, the other
> British.
>
> - *And, for fear that he should suspect how her heart was aching, she gave a particularly brilliant and joyous smile* - [1911] Eleanor H. Porter »
>   Miss Billy Married » Chapter XX. Arkwright's Eyes are Opened.
> - *Is there any one you want to see, or anything of that sort?' and doing it as steadily as possible for fear that he should mistake the
>   carelessness of whisky for the distraction of fear, I got my candle
>   alight* - [1902] H.G. Wells » The Story of the Inexperienced Ghost.
>
> The Google 5grams illustrate the increasing currency of *would*
> against *should* in this construction, in both American and British
> English.

The most idiomatic answers would use '... would fall behand' and ' ... might fall behind'.

Comment: I checked out the most common word to follow **for fear that he** in NGrams. In descending order of popularity, it's **would, might, may, will, should, was, could, has, is.** And drilling down on even the *last* verb in that list gives me at least dozens of hits. But it's certainly quite clear that **would** is far more common than **should** today - whereas it was the complete opposite, 150 years ago.

Comment: *Here we have a subjunctive created by a modal auxiliary and this would naturally be should* — This needs a bit clarification. A helpful answer! Thanks, @Edwin Ashworth.

Comment: ... Yes. 'Here, on the other hand, we have a subjunctive created by a modal auxiliary ...'. As FumbleFingers says, 150 years ago, 'should' would have been the default choice in such constructions. // But not today. //// It's interesting (if statistically insignificant) to see that the non-modal variant 'for fear that he fall behind' only has a token in the Google ngram '_UK_ English' corpus.